# Noughts and Crosses Issue part 2

Tags: python, if-statement

Keeping in mind I am a beginner programmer,
i've ran into another problem with my noughts and crosses code in my attempt to add functionality to not allow players to place on the same grid space more than once- however I cannot figure out why it is that when you enter a position for the first go it immediately states that you >Cannot place on a full grid space   even though it is impossible for any spaces to be full.

````
    won = False

    sum = 0
    for i in range (3):
        if grid[i][i] == "X":
            sum +=1
        elif grid[i][i] == "O":
            sum -=1
    if sum == 3 or sum == -3:
        won = True

    sum = 0
    for i in range (3):
        if grid[row][i] == "X":
            sum +=1
        elif grid[row][i] == "O":
            sum -=1
    if sum == 3 or sum == -3:
        won = True

    sum = 0
    for i in range (3):
        if grid[i][column] == "X":
            sum +=1
        elif grid[i][column] == "O":
            sum -=1
    if sum == 3 or sum == -3:
        won = True    

    return won


  
#############################main program#############################  
grid = [["-","-","-"],
        ["-","-","-"],
        ["-","-","-"]]
for x in grid:
    print (x)

win = False
repeat = False


while win == False:
    print("\nCrosses\n")
    while repeat == False:
        column = int(input("Enter a Column\n"))
        row = int(input("Enter a Row\n"))
        if grid[row][column] == "X" or "O":
            print("Cannot place on a full grid space")
        else:
            repeat == True
        grid[row][column] = ("X")
    for x in grid: print (x)
    win = checkwin(grid, row, column)
    if win:
        break
    repeat = False
    print("\nNoughts\n")
    column = int(input("Enter a Column\n"))
    row = int(input("Enter a Row\n"))
    grid[row][column] = ("O")
    for x in grid: print (x)  
    win = checkwin(grid, row, column)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out your code and found a couple of issues that were tripping you up.  Following is a revised version of your code with the corrections having a comment.

```
def checkwin(grid, row, column):    # Added the function definition

    won = False

    sum = 0
    for i in range (3):
        if grid[i][i] == "X":
            sum +=1
        elif grid[i][i] == "O":
            sum -=1
    if sum == 3 or sum == -3:
        won = True

    sum = 0
    for i in range (3):
        if grid[row][i] == "X":
            sum +=1
        elif grid[row][i] == "O":
            sum -=1
    if sum == 3 or sum == -3:
        won = True

    sum = 0
    for i in range (3):
        if grid[i][column] == "X":
            sum +=1
        elif grid[i][column] == "O":
            sum -=1
    if sum == 3 or sum == -3:
        won = True    

    return won

  
#############################main program#############################  
grid = [["-","-","-"],
        ["-","-","-"],
        ["-","-","-"]]
for x in grid:
    print (x)

win = False
repeat = False

while win == False:
    print("\nCrosses\n")
    while repeat == False:
        column = int(input("Enter a Column\n"))
        row = int(input("Enter a Row\n"))
        if grid[row][column] == "X" or grid[row][column] == "O":    # Revised the test
            print("Cannot place on a full grid space")
        else:
            repeat = True                       # Removed second "=" sign
        grid[row][column] = ("X")
    for x in grid: print (x)
    win = checkwin(grid, row, column)
    if win:
        break
    repeat = False
    print("\nNoughts\n")
    column = int(input("Enter a Column\n"))
    row = int(input("Enter a Row\n"))
    grid[row][column] = ("O")
    for x in grid: print (x)  
    win = checkwin(grid, row, column)
```

Following are the highlights.

- The sample code was missing the function definition for checking for a winner so that was added.
- The "if" test for empty grid positions needed to be corrected checking for not having an "X" nor having an "O".
- The update of "repeat" variable only needed one "=", not "==" (that's an equality check).

After that the program seemed to play properly.  Give that try.